# Wifi problems on linux Modelo: QCA9565 / AR9565

Tags: firmware, fedora

Here is the HTML version of the steps to modify parameters of the Bluetooth ath9k module:

## Modify parameters of the Bluetooth ath9k module in Linux

To modify the parameters of the ath9k kernel module that controls your WiFi/Bluetooth chipset, you can follow these steps:

1. Edit the module configuration file. For example to enable Bluetooth antenna diversity:

   ```
   sudo echo 1 > /sys/module/ath9k/parameters/bt_ant_diversity
   ```
2. To make the change permanent, you must edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
   ```
3. Add the line with the desired parameter, for example:

   ```
   options ath9k bt_ant_diversity=1
   ```
4. Save the file and reboot for the changes to take effect:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
5. Verify that the new value has been applied:

   ```
   grep -H '' /sys/module/ath9k*/parameters/* | grep bt_ant_diversity
   ```

You should see `bt_ant_diversity:1` now.

This way you can configure different parameters to test improvements in connectivity, stability, speed, etc. Consult the ath9k driver documentation for more details on the available parameters.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This is an English only website, so please translate your question.

Comment: This is not a question.